# остановить скрипт

Tags: php

Задам такой глупый вопрос,у меня код загружает картинку на сервер,все хорошо работает,но когда я удаляю картинку из папки и перезагружаю страницу она у меня снова туда забрасывается даже если я форму загрузки картинки не трогал просто перезагрузил страницу.
P.s да я могу загуглить, но я не могу сформировать запрос - думал что то "как остановить выполнения скрипта" и тд

```
 include('set.php');
include ('lib/WideImage.php');  


$path = 'scr/';
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['img']['name']));
$pic = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['img']['name']));
$new_name = date("d.m.Y").'-'.$_FILES['img']['name'];
$full_path = $path.$new_name; 



if($_FILES['img']['error'] == 0){
if (($pic!="jpg")  &&  ($pic!="png")  &&  ($pic!="jpeg")){
    echo "Файл не был загружен, загрузите файл с расширением .jpeg/jpg/png";
exit();  

}
else {





if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){
WideImage::load($_FILES['img']['name'])->resize(200, 200)->saveToFile($full_path);
    }
    }
}



if(isset($_POST['add']))
{  

$result = mysql_query('
INSERT INTO obj
(`img`)
VALUES
("' . $full_path . '")
');

    mysql_close;
    echo "Картинка добавлена";
}
```

Comment: die(); - останавливает выполнение скрипта

Comment: @G.Denis это в конце всего php кода?

Comment: Где нужно остановить выполнение там и пишите

Comment: @G.Denis добавил часть кода для ясности

Comment: После загрузки файла, перекидывайте через header на какой нибудь index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пользуетесь нативным РНР или фреймворком?

Когда Вы делаете POST отправку формы и после этого, перед перезагрузкой страницы вручную, оно Вам выдает окошко, что есть данные, которые можно повторно отправить - просто сделайте `unset($_POST)`.

Если у Вас загрузка с помощью AJAX - то нужно сделать `reset` формы, которую Вы отправляли.

Пример на чистом РНР:

```
class Uploader
{

    /**
     * @param array $file_array
     * @param bool $key
     * @param bool $postKey
     * @return bool
     */
    public function upload($file_array = [], $key = false, $postKey = false){

        unset($_POST[$postKey]);

        if (array_key_exists($key, $file_array)){
            foreach ($file_array[$key] as $file) {
                $mover = move_uploaded_file($file['path'], '/destination/folder/and/file.extension');
                return $mover;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['add'])){
    var_dump((new Uploader())->upload($_FILES, 'img', 'add'));
}
```

Comment: добавил код как у меня все это представлено

Comment: @Michael, У Вас проверка на POST - после подгрузки картинки. Она должна идти перед ней.

Comment: но она у меня для заноса в БД

Comment: @Michael, добавил для Вас пример

Comment: @Michael, скажите, если сработает корректно

Comment: не получилось все равно картинку заново закидывает и в БД создает под новым id

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50461/discussion-between-roman-kozin-and-michael).